# Redirect from React's Context API component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-context

I am trying to redirect from my context following a failed update of the state from the a cookie.

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export const MyContext = createContext();

const cookies = new Cookies();

class MyProvider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setStateFromCookie();
  }

  setStateFromCookie = () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ data: cookies.get('my-cookie')['data'] });
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    return 
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyProvider);
```

I am using a withRouter hook to this.props.history.push('/'), becuase the context is wrapping the router

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MyProvider>
          <div className="MyApp">
            <Router>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Index} />
              <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            </Router>
          </div>
        </MyProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default MyApp;
```

The problem is that the redirect to the home page following the error, but the home page isn't rendering.. I still see the dashboard page.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have a nested Router wrapping your Routes. You need to remove that and then everything will work fine

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <MyProvider>
      <div className="MyApp">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Index} />
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      </div>
    </MyProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

When you use a nested Router, and try to navigate from Provider, the history used by Provider is being provided by `BrowserRouter` and hence it isn't able to communicate to the Routes whcih are dependent on the inner `<Router>` component for history.

Using a single router wrapping your components solves this issue

Comment: How do you mean?? If I remove BrowserRouter this.props.history.push('/'); in my context won't work anymore..

Comment: You don't remove BrowserRouter, remove the Router wrapping `<Route>`. Check the post please. I have shown how it should look like